# AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I'm getting this error when I try to create a factorplot with seaborn in an ipython notebook.

Here's the end of the stack trace:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/axes.pyc in get_legend_handles_labels(self, legend_handler_map)
   4317             label = handle.get_label()
   4318             #if (label is not None and label != '' and not label.startswith('_')):
-> 4319             if label and not label.startswith('_'):
   4320                 handles.append(handle)
   4321                 labels.append(label)

AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

Here are my imports:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series,DataFrame

import math

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
%matplotlib inline

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

from sklearn import metrics

import statsmodels.api as sm
```

And here's my code:

```
df = sm.datasets.fair.load_pandas().data
df['had_affair'] = df.affairs.apply(lambda x: 1 if x != 0 else 0)
sns.factorplot('age', data=df, hue='had_affair', palette='coolwarm')
```

The problem seems to be that the column I'm using for the `hue` is an integer and not a string. Creating a new column using something like `df['had_affair_str'] = df.had_affair.apply(str)` and then using `had_affair_str` as my `hue` makes the error go away, but the online tutorial I'm following uses this exact code without getting any errors. Is this a known issue with matplotlib or seaborn? Is one of my packages out of date?

Here are the versions for my python packages:

```
ipython==3.1.0
numpy==1.9.2
pandas==0.16.1
matplotlib==1.4.3
seaborn==0.5.1
scikit-learn==0.16.1
statsmodels==0.6.1
```

edit:

Output from `df.info()`:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 6366 entries, 0 to 6365
Data columns (total 11 columns):
rate_marriage      6366 non-null float64
age                6366 non-null float64
yrs_married        6366 non-null float64
children           6366 non-null float64
religious          6366 non-null float64
educ               6366 non-null float64
occupation         6366 non-null float64
occupation_husb    6366 non-null float64
affairs            6366 non-null float64
had_affair         6366 non-null int64
had_affair_str     6366 non-null object
dtypes: float64(9), int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 596.8+ KB
```

Comment: are you sure 'label' is always a string ?,  if label and not label.startswith('_'): i believe u are expecting it to be string and its coming int64 use dtype to check.

Comment: I'm following an online tutorial where the instructor uses the same code, but with no error. In addition to that, it just doesn't make sense to me that matplotlib can't handle using a non-string column as a label. It seems that it should be smart enough to call `str` somewhere if it needs to use `startswith`. I've updated my question to make it clear that I believe that this code should run without errors.

Comment: Your code ran fine for me without any dtype conversion, can you post the output from `df.info()`

Comment: well. "smart enough"  kinda has no specific definition. But it should be nice to have I agree. But the whole idea of software lies fundamentally on an agreed contract of method parameters.  :)

Comment: @EdChum edited my post to include the output of `df.info()`

Comment: Should have worked, also my python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn and numpy match yours so unclear what the problem, could you try restarting your ipython session

Comment: @EdChum re-ran `ipython notebook` but still no luck

Comment: `plt.plot(range(3), label=4); plt.legend()` Does that work as expected?

Comment: @tcaswell nope, i get a similar error: `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'startswith'`

Comment: startswith is a string method... but here its getting a different data type..... Check your data first... You can do type conversion,  Try converting to str ... eg: str(value).startswith('v'). This will return either True or False even if data type of value is int, instead of giving an error normally .

Answer (score 0):

matplotlib is expecting the dtypes of your label series `had_affair` to be object/string, but it's numpy.int64

You can forcely convert the numpy.int64 into string using this:

```
df['had_affair'] = df['had_affair'].astype(str)
```